# Public variable doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Public Class sample
  Public inta As Integer
  Protected Sub button1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    inta = "2"
  End Sub

  Protected Sub button2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Response.Write(inta)
  End Sub
End Class
```

This is a sample code behind of my aspx. It keeps on showing 0 instead of 2. The only difference in my code to this sample one is that button2 is in a modal dialog. But when i tried using this simple code it still doesn't work.. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: Why is it declared as an Integer if your assigning a String to it?

Comment: Not really your answer but you should better start to use Option Strict On

Comment: Since this is ASPX, your missing the fact that there is a postback occurring and this variable has no value(hence 0) with the page reloading. You should read up on the `Page Life Cycle`. You would have to store the value in a Session variable to retain it's value.

Comment: You should read on how the web work first. Each page is stateless, this mean that on every post-back you loose all of your saved information unless it's in a container like a session/cache/viewstate.

Comment: didn't thought of that. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a Public variable from what I can see so limit the scope to the lowest needed. You can use a Property like this:

```
Public Class sample

  Private Property IntA As Integer
    Get
      Return TryCast(Session("IntA"), Integer)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
      Session("IntA") = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Protected Sub button1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    IntA = 2
  End Sub

 Protected Sub button2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Response.Write(IntA.ToString)
 End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @IWantToLearn, did you see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable `inta` as `Shared`:

```
Public Shared inta As Integer
```